# How to use regex to search minimal range

Tags: regex

I have this string (for example)

```
abcd CCC abcd abcd CCC abcd abcd BBB abcd abcd DDD abcd abcd CCC abcd
```

and need find minimal range substring inlude BBB from CCC to DDD

> abcd CCC abcd abcd **CCC abcd abcd BBB abcd abcd DDD** abcd abcd CCC abcd

but my regexp dosen't work ((

```
/(?!.+CCC).+BBB.+DDD/i
```

This regexp work for string without last CCC, but that no well...

[Live examle on regexr.com](http://regexr.com?389t4)

Help me please and sorry my English =)

Comment: Do you want the smallest _overall_, or the smallest first? In other words, for `abcd CCC 1111 CCC 2222 abcd BBB abcd DDD abcd CCC 3333 BBB abcd DDD`, do you expect to find `CCC 2222 abcd BBB abcd DDD` or `CCC 3333 BBB abcd DDD`?

Comment: I need _smallest first_. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
CCC(?:(?!CCC).)*?BBB(?:(?!CCC.*?BBB).)*?DDD
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/fV3yW8

Comment: That doesn't work if there's a `CCC` between `BBB` and `DDD`. I understand what you're trying to do, but I think you're missing a part.

Comment: Yes that's true and as per my understanding of the the question it shouldn't match. If minimal string from `CCC to DDD` doesn't contain `BBB` then there should not be a match.

Comment: Okay, that's not how interpreted it. If the input is `abcd CCC abcd abcd CCC abcd abcd BBB abcd CCC abcd DDD abcd abcd CCC abcd` (slightly modified from your test input), I think it should match `CCC abcd abcd BBB abcd CCC abcd DDD`.

Comment: Still no, since you want the smallest possible. If the input is `abcd CCC abcd abcd CCC abcd abcd BBB abcd CCC BBB abcd DDD abcd abcd CCC abcd`, yours will match `CCC abcd abcd BBB abcd CCC BBB abcd DDD` instead of `CCC BBB abcd DDD` like it (probably) should.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CCC(?:(?!CCC).)*BBB(?:(?!CCC.*BBB).)*DDD
```

It matches the `CCC` closest to `BBB`, then it checks if there's not another `CCC ...something... BBB` until the final `DDD`.
Given the following input string, the match is in bold

> abcd CCC abcd abcd **CCC abcd abcd BBB abcd CCC abcd DDD** abcd abcd CCC abcd

---

Note however, that it will find the *smallest* form of the *first* of such a sequence. If there's a smaller `CCC ...something... BBB ...something... DDD` further down the string, it will not find it. I don't think any regex will.
So for the following input string, the match is in bold, while the shortest overall is in italic:

> abcd CCC abcd abcd **CCC abcd abcd BBB abcd DDD** abcd abcd *CCC abcd BBB abcd DDD* abcd